# Batch Scripting Adventure

Tags: windows, if-statement, batch-file

Here is my batch script file. There are 2 scenarios

---

- Scenario 1

---

```
@echo off
set name=
set /P TypeName=Name: %=%

if %TypeName% == "abcd" goto correctName
else goto wrongName

:correctName
echo Correct Name
:end

:wrongName
echo Wrong Name
:end
```

When i type abcd as the input, i get **'else' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file**

**Wrong Name**

---

- Scenario 2

---

```
@echo off
set name=
set /P TypeName=Name: %=%

if %TypeName% EQA "abcd" goto correctName
if %TypeName% NEQ "abcd" goto wrongName

:correctName
echo Correct Name
:end

:wrongName
echo Wrong Name
:end
```

When i type abcd as the input, i get **EQA was unexpected at this time.**

Is there something wrong in my script?Am I missing something here

Comment: By the way, you can also use `IF NOT something == somethingelse …`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To give an end to this post,i got the expected output this way-

```
@echo off
set name=
set /P TypeName=Name: %=%

if "%TypeName%" == "abcd" (
echo Correct Name
) else (
echo Wrong Name
)
```

Answer (score 1):

1. `ELSE` should be on the same line with the `IF` keyword or on the same line with the closing bracket that pertains to the `IF`.

   Like this:

   ```
   IF %TypeName% == "abcd" GOTO correctName ELSE GOTO wrongName
   ```

   Or like this:

   ```
   IF %TypeName% == "abcd" (
     ECHO Correct.
     GOTO correctName
   ) ELSE GOTO wrongName
   ```
2. The correct keyword for the *Equal* operator is `EQU`:

   ```
   IF %TypeName% EQU "abcd" GOTO correctName
   ```

Comment: It's a different issue. You need to jump over the `:wrongName` part after echoing `Correct Name`. Try putting `GOTO :EOF` after `ECHO Correct Name`. And you cannot use two labels with the same name (I mean the `:end` labels).

Comment: I followed this solution of yours-
IF %TypeName% == "abcd" GOTO correctName ELSE GOTO wrongName
and
if %TypeName% EQU "abcd" goto correctName else goto wrongName

and i got-
Correct Name
Wrong Name

Then i followed this solution of yours-
IF %TypeName% == "abcd" (
  ECHO Correct.
  GOTO correctName
) ELSE GOTO wrongName

and i got-
Wrong Name

Comment: Actually i'm trying to say that there is a problem in my if condition.It's not validating even though i'm giving the right input value.

Comment: Your question becomes too broad. You cannot seriously expect me to solve all the issues of your sample script in one go. Please play a while with what you've got from all the answers here. If anything else crops up, post a new question (if it is indeed a different one, which so far it proves to be the case). I guess by your replies that the issues I've addressed in my answer are solved.

Comment: You need to put `%TypeName%` in double quotes, that's what first springs to mind. If that doesn't help, please post a new question. This one becomes messy.

Answer (score 0):

The first example is almost right, except that the format of an IF/ELSE statement in a batch file is as follow:

```
IF <statement>  (
..
..
) ELSE (
...
...
)
```

So just you use that format and it should work.

Comment: would it make any difference? Coz I'm using only one statement under both conditions

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't necessarily need to use the else, like this

```
@echo off
set name=
set /P TypeName=Name: %=%

if %TypeName% == "abcd" goto correctName
goto wrongName

:correctName
echo Correct Name
:end

:wrongName
echo Wrong Name
:end
```

If the %TypeName% == "abcd" it will jump to :correctName, if it doesn't it will simply fall to the next line and jump to :wrongName.

Comment: This didn't work either. I enter "abcd" as the input and it still gives me "Wrong Name" as the output

No matter what happens,it's jumping to the else condition.

Comment: I'm not really sure, something appears to be going wrong although the code should be working, I have had issues with batch before where for some reason the code will just not work. Try re - writing a new batch with another variable name and try again.

Comment: I've answered my own question.It worked for me that way.I had to surround %TypeName% with " "..

Comment: Great, I'm glad you got it sorted.